# angularJS Unknown provider error for custom service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a simple angularJS app scaffolded with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/codelab/). I'm trying to set up the Google Calendar API so it can be accessed as a service. However, I keep getting

```
angular.js:13294 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
googleApiServiceProvider <- googleApiService <- MainCtrl
```

I've checked for all the simple solutions I could find (that the service is declared as a dependency in app.js, that it is spelled correctly, it's included in index.html, etc) but the error still comes up.

index.html

```
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/gapi.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('mytodoApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngTable',
    'ui.sortable',
    'LocalStorageModule',
    'googleApiService'
]).config(['localStorageServiceProvider', function(localStorageServiceProvider){
    localStorageServiceProvider.setPrefix('ls');
}])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'main'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
});
```

main.js

```
angular.module('mytodoApp').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,  
$http, NgTableParams, localStorageService, googleApiService) {...}
```

gapi.js

```
angular.module('googleApiService', []).service('gapiService', function() {...});
```

The contents of gapi.js is the JavaScript [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js), with some minor modifications. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help point out what I'm doing wrong, as I am new to angular and JavaScript in general.

Comment: I think you need to name the modules the same right? Right now it looks mytodoApp is looking for another module that already has been created, while the googleApiService is creating it's own module called googleApiService. So for example. your main would be angular.module('mytodoApp' []) and the gapi.js would be angular.module('mytodoApp').service...

Comment: Are you use the service isn't called `gapiService`? That's what your gapi.js file seems to indicate. Your module is fine and it is getting injected, its most likely the name of the service is wrong.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much Jeremy! I feel so dumb after looking at it for over an hour trying to figure out where I went wrong. The service was indeed supposed to be `googleApiService` but I forgot to change the name in gapi.js.